# Battleship scanner to joptionpane

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I am writing a battleship game which require me to use the joptionpane, but I really have trouble of understanding that. I have everything set up in scanner and I need helps from converting scanner to joptionpane!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class battleShip {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];
    int[][] ships = new int[3][2];
    int[] shoot = new int[2];
    int attempts=0,
        shotHit=0;

    initBoard(board);
    initShips(ships);

    System.out.println();

    do{
        showBoard(board);
        shoot(shoot);
        attempts++;

        if(hit(shoot,ships)){
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
            shotHit++;
        }                
        else
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);

        changeboard(shoot,ships,board);


    }while(shotHit!=3);

    System.out.println("\n\n\nBattleship Java game finished! You hit 3 ships in "+attempts+" attempts");
    showBoard(board);
}

public static void initBoard(int[][] board){
    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ )
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ )
            board[row][column]=-1;
}

public static void showBoard(int[][] board){
    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
    System.out.println();

    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ ){
        System.out.print((row+1)+"");
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ ){
            if(board[row][column]==-1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"~");
            }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                System.out.print("\t"+"*");
            }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"X");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void initShips(int[][] ships){
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int ship=0 ; ship < 3 ; ship++){
        ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
        ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);

        //let's check if that shot was already tried 
        //if it was, just finish the do...while when a new pair was randomly selected
        for(int last=0 ; last < ship ; last++){
            if( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) )
                do{
                    ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
                    ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);
                }while( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) );
        }

    }
}

public static void shoot(int[] shoot){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[0]--;

    System.out.print("Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[1]--;

}

public static boolean hit(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){

    for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
        if( shoot[0]==ships[ship][0] && shoot[1]==ships[ship][1]){
            System.out.printf("You hit a ship located in (%d,%d)\n",shoot[0]+1,shoot[1]+1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void hint(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int attempt){
    int row=0,
        column=0;

    for(int line=0 ; line < ships.length ; line++){
        if(ships[line][0]==shoot[0])
            row++;
        if(ships[line][1]==shoot[1])
            column++;
    }

    System.out.printf("\nHint %d: \nRow %d -> %d ships\n" +
                             "Column %d -> %d ships\n",attempt,shoot[0]+1,row,shoot[1]+1,column);
}

public static void changeboard(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int[][] board){
    if(hit(shoot,ships))
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=1;
    else
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=0;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which the issue do you have?

Comment: I wonder if this can be change from scanner to joptionpane (dialogs box)